# Where does the "Mailing" data come from in the Mail Opened Report?

Tags: civireport

When we run the Mail Open Report and include the "Mailing" Field it does not return consistent data.  We expected it to return the latest mailing opened but it does not and the title of the mailing is not consistent with the subject in the Mailings file which can be found when I click on the individual contact and review their mailings.

How can I return the most recently opened email with the contact for this report?

We are using version: CiviCRM 4.6.18.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to indicate your CiviCRM version?

Comment: If you are looking for a list of contacts that have opened a specific mailing you might be better off first locating the mailing you are interested in from the list of 'Scheduled and Sent Mailings', and then click on the report link from that view. This shows a number of key bits of information about the given mailing, including the number of 'tracked opens'. To the right of this stat is a link to the 'Mail Opened' report specific to the mailing you are interested in.

Comment: Also you should bear in mind that the number reported as 'tracked opens' should be considered as indicative rather than accurate given the variability in how mail clients are configured.

Comment: Also, the title of a mailing is not the same as the subject line. The title is an administrative label, whereas the subject is what the recipient gets to see.

Comment: Thank you Graham, we are trying to automate the report so we contact those people who have changed a behaviour and want to use the most recent email.